# Angular 2 Deployment

Tags: angularjs, angular, deployment

When using Angular 1, development is easy, just quote script in html such as 
            Deployment is just copy a few .js/.html/.css files to my iis server. 
            However, when testing with Angular 2, many npm/typescript packages (more than 500 files) are included in a simple hellow world webpage.
            Is there any tools that help for deploying Angular 2 apps?

thanks
mintssoul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 2 comes with many build options.Most popular and recommended one is Angular cli.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

It uses web pack which is powerful framework for building client side applications and minification,bundling,cache bursting, even gzip compression are inbuilt which are great to reduce package footprint and make your life easier for angular 2 application build and deployment.

App specific file copying or custom logic can be incorporated using gulp : http://gulpjs.com/